# Browser keyboard shortcut for focusing first focusable element

Tags: browser, accessibility, focus

Are there keyboard shortcuts in browsers to bring the element focus (tab key) back to the first focusable element on the current page?

Answer (score 0):

The closest approaching solution is to refresh the page contents with <kbd>F5</kbd>. Of course, if you had started typing text in input fields, that will make you lose your text.

Another solution is to turn on Caret browsing by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> which makes the caret move at the top of the page. If the first element is located at the first character of the page, it's automatically selected, otherwise press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the first element. If needed, you may turn off the Caret browsing by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> again.

This second solution works at least for Edge and Chrome.

Comment: This should be a comment I believe. It isn't bad info, but without some explanation of how and/or why there may not be a way to focus the first element in the page, it is currently more of a comment.

Comment: The question is clear to me. I guess that you may downvote this answer and it will get deleted automatically soon. Till that happens and there's no other answer, at least visitors can find one clear solution. As you asked, I tried to complete it a little bit, but I have no reference to mention, it's just user experience. I'd be glad to remove my answer as soon as someone proposes a better answer.